# Long to String...Not your usual convert

Tags: c#, character-encoding

Just for being curious I was rummaging through some code to do diff's on files. I've got it al working etc but one of the points it writes the following

```
    long test = 0x3034464649445342L;
```

I understand that that this is just another way to write...

```
    long test = 3473478480300364610;
```

...but when it writes to a file it prints out as 'BSDIFF40'. Can anyone shed some light on how this is converted? I've tried different encodings (ANSI, ASCII etc) but can't figure it out. The line that writes it to the file is below if that helps anyone...

```
    private static void WriteInt64(long value, byte[] buf, int offset)
    {
        var valueToWrite = value < 0 ? -value : value;

        for (var byteIndex = 0; byteIndex < 8; byteIndex++)
        {
            buf[offset + byteIndex] = (byte)(valueToWrite % 256);
            valueToWrite -= buf[offset + byteIndex];
            valueToWrite /= 256;
        }

        if (value < 0)
            buf[offset + 7] |= 0x80;
    }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't see where your code is dealing with *text* at all. It's converting populating a `byte[]` from a `long`... what does that have to do with character  encodings? (As an aside, I'd use `& 0xff` instead of `% 256`, and `>> 8` instead of `/ 256`.)

Comment: 0x3034464649445342L (or 3473478480300364610) when written to a text file using the above method writes out 'BSDIFF40' (this is purposely done as it is commented in the code that this is what it would write). I want to figure out how this conversion is done as I can't figure out what format it is writing in.

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't write it out to a text file at all though - it populates a byte array. What are you doing with that byte array? If you're writing the bytes straight to a file, then that's not really a text file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you are doing to print the values in the file is interpreting these values as [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) encoded text:

```
0x30 = '0'
0x34 = '4'
0x46 = 'F'
0x46 = 'F'
0x49 = 'I'
0x44 = 'D'
0x53 = 'S'
0x42 = 'B'
```

Comment: Perfect thank you, I'll accept the answer when it lets me :). Saying 3 minute wait :).